# How can I count HTML elements on a printed page using CSS?

Tags: css, printing, count, element

I am trying to print a repeating header on a dynamically generated HTML page in print.

The header shows a logo, and uses CSS to display page numbers.

My site lets users add blocks of text, or collages of images, and adds them independently with "add text" and "add image" buttons.

the resultant code is (somewhat) as follows: (slim/HAML syntax)

```
editable-section.ng-cloak(
      ng-repeat='section in story.sections'
      editable='false'
    ) 
      = render 'header'
      .show-content-wrapper
        = render 'sections/section'
```

The size of this content can vary wildly, and so I don't want to place a 'page-break-before:always;" rule before each ... because I may want them to stack more than one on a page to save paper and not look silly.

My problem is, inside each editable-section, I have an HTML header I only want to display if this is the first editable-section on the page.

So the question is, how would I only display the first header on each printed page? I imagine it would be something to the effect of:

```
@media only print {
  @page {
    header {
      display:none;
      &:first-of-type {
        display:block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, "You can't change all CSS properties with @page. You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of this javascript?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]
```

With the brackets you can select a particular element with the 0th being the first.

Does this help?

Comment: Well, I could have 1 editable-content section per page, or I could have three... the idea of the site is to let the user provide as little or as much content as they want... so using indexes only is valuable when I have static content where I know what is to appear... and I don't. I only want to show a header for the first editable-content section on the page, but not a possible second, or third, or nth.